# Problem with Convenience Inits for SKSpriteNodes and assigning Variable values

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, sprite-kit, sktexture

I've been programming for about 2 years, and as such can usually debug my way out of a certain problem but I can't seem to figure this one out.

I'm currently attempting to make a procedurally generated character generation method for one of my newer games still in the making. One of the many properties a character can have is clothing. As such, each clothing item needs to animate when the player runs, or attacks etc. I figured I could create multiple layers (SKSprites) on the character and animate each one separately for each layer of clothing.

Currently, I have a Convenience Init for each clothing item that takes the original image name, and assigns it to a few variables. One of these is an array of SKTextures: `[SKTextures]` which is the container for my running animations. Essentially, from the original image name, I use string interpolation to form a list of running layers for that certain clothing layer.

Here is my Clothing Class for reference:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class Clothing: SKSpriteNode {

    var staticImage = SKTexture()

    var runningAnimation : [SKTexture] = []
    var attackingAnimation : [SKTexture] = []
    var idleAnimation : [SKTexture] = []
    var deathAnimation : [SKTexture] = []

    convenience init(image: String) {
        self.init()
        staticImage = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: image)


        for i in 0...3 {
            runningAnimation.append(SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "\(image)Running\(i)"))
            //            attackingAnimation.append(SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "\(image)attack\(i)"))
            //            idleAnimation.append(SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "\(image)idle\(i)"))
            //            deathAnimation.append(SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "\(image)dying\(i)"))
        }

        self.texture = staticImage
    }

    func animate(animation: String) {

        var animate = SKAction()

        if animation == "run" {
            print(staticImage)
            animate = SKAction.animate(with: runningAnimation, timePerFrame: 0.15)
        }
    }
}
```

However my problem comes from the actual calling of `animate(animation: "run")` from the character class.

I'm met with a response in the debugger that's as follows:

```
2019-12-23 02:51:43.342512-0500 No Man's Land[6390:1805219] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'SKAction animateWithTextures: textures array cannot be empty'
```

I have tried adding print functions just just under my `for i in` loop to make sure that it's actually adding the textures and it is. If you look above, I also printed the `staticImage` when calling the animation function to see if something is happening when this function is called and I got an odd response
in the Debugger:

```
<SKTexture> 'caucasianMaleHead' (160 x 160)
<SKTexture> '(null)' (0 x 0)
```

There is only one print function, and it seems as if it removes the value of the `SKTexture` that was assigned in the original `init`.

I've come to the conclusion that it must be something that happens when the animate function is called, but I'm not sure what, nor why it would remove values of previously set variables. I could be wrong though.

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you!

Comment: You’re calling animate twice, but on what objects? It might help if you show the code that’s doing the calls. Also, calling the texture initializer doesn’t actually load anything and is no guarantee that the images exist.  I’d suggest checking that the image names are ok first. You can force texture loading by calling size() for the textures. (Also you don’t need to write SKTexture.init, just SKTexture(imageNamed: ...))

Comment: Based on coding style, maybe you’re calling just Clothing() somewhere, i.e., not the image: init, then calling animate on that uninitialized object.

Comment: I agree with @bg2b, but I think you are calling Clothing(imageNamed:) not Clothing(image), since Clothing() would not render any texture, which you would have noticed.